# Covering a $n$-holed torus for $n\geq 2$ with a hyperbolic tesselation?

Tags: general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

How can I cover a $n$-holed torus $(n\ge2)$ with $\frac{2-2n}{\frac pq-\frac p{2}+1}$ faces of regular hyperbolic tesselation {p,q}? I don't need the graphics, just the construction. For example, in the image at http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/klein.html, the construction is an array$[56][3]$, which have each element from $1$ to $24$ ($24$ vertices) to describe which faces are created by which vertices. I just need to find a coloring pattern for a hyperbolic tessellation.

Edit: Assume the fraction is an integer. It is calculated directly from Euclid function V-E+F=2-2n.

Edit2: A way of going to its another copies in hyperbolic plane is also enough. There is also an example in http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/klein.html. It is pretty on Klein's quartic, but probably not on other tessellations.

Comment: This is not going to be easy. First of all, unless you put some extra conditions on $n$, $p$, and $q$, no such tesselation is guaranteed to exist. At the very least, that complicated and hard-to-read fraction might not be an integer.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380335/is-a-regular-tessellation-p-q-always-possible-on-some-closed-surface-s).